# root caused by java.lang.nosuchmethoderror javax.ws.rs.clienterrorexception.validate

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c, jboss-eap-6

I have a RESTEasy project on JBoss-EAP-6.0.1 now I want to deploy war in Weblogic server and I am getting this exception So, Is it possible to deploy RESTEasy project war into WebLogic ?

Comment: Please provide more explanations. What exception you're getting? Provide some code!

Comment: root cause of Servletzexception by java.lang.nosuchmethoderror : javax.ws.rs.clienterrorexception.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;

Comment: You are probably including jee jars in your war

Comment: How to tell weblogic to force to use resteasy library, any weblogic.xml entry?